# How to add a custom file extension that has a dot (blade.php) in NetBeans?

Tags: php, netbeans, laravel, laravel-blade

I need to assign a custom extension to be recognized as a twig file in netbeans ('blade.php' as 'twig' file and give me syntax highlighting and code completion appropriately). The problem with using the File association option (in `Tools > Options > Miscellaneous > Files`) 
is that it won't let me add '.' in extension like blade.php, it works with single worded extensions like php, html, css etc.

Will be grateful if anybody can help me with this!

Comment: You might get a response through the [Netbeans forums](http://forums.netbeans.org/) / [bug tracker](https://netbeans.org/community/issues.html)

Comment: **Indeed** till now NB 8.2 has no any support for `blade.php` all the next tries are not completed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I can see the problem is more *NetBeans-centric*, so I would also suggest you to file a bug report to the NetBeans community.

- [The NetBeans forums](http://forums.netbeans.org/).
- [The NetBeans bug tracker](https://netbeans.org/community/issues.html).

Maybe in the future they can fix that issue. You may also link that question so they can see the user reactions.

Answer (score 26):

Workaround I figured out and seems to work (at least Netbeans 8.x+)

- Go to `Tools > Options > Miscellaneous > Files`
- Click <kbd>New</kbd>
- Enter *blade* as the new extension (you can use anything here, but this seems the most natural)
- Click <kbd>OK</kbd>
- In `Associate File Type (MIME)` select *TWIG (text/x-twig)*
- Click <kbd>OK</kbd> of the whole `Options` window
- Close Netbeans
- Open the Netbeans configuration folder - on Windows it's `%AppData%\Netbeans\<version>\`
- Go to subfolder `config\Services\MIMEResolver`
- Open `user-defined-mime-resolver.xml`
- Find the `<ext name="blade"/>` entry (or whatever you entred above)
- Change the *blade* to *blade.php*
- Save and close the file

Voilà, higlighting should now work in Netbeans IDE :)

Comment: Does not seem to work for me on NetBeans 8.0.2 on Fedora Linux.

Comment: It is good, but what is the next step to have a blade highlighting? Thank you.

Comment: Very helpful, thank you! For the record, the file path on Mac is: `/Users/username/Library/Application Support/NetBeans/version/config/Services/MIMEResolver/user-defined-mime-resolver.xml`

Comment: this didn't change anything for me... =(

Comment: This is clever but it didn't work with NetBeans 11.2.

Answer (score 14):

Modify the `user-defined-mime-resolver.xml` file so that it looks *something* like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE MIME-resolver PUBLIC "-//NetBeans//DTD MIME Resolver 1.1//EN" "http://www.netbeans.org/dtds/mime-resolver-1_1.dtd">
<MIME-resolver>
    <file>
        <ext name="php"/>
        <name name=".blade" substring="true"/>
        <resolver mime="text/x-twig"/>
    </file>
    <file>
    <ext name="php"/>
        <resolver mime="text/x-php5"/>
    </file>
</MIME-resolver>
```

On Linux (Ubuntu), you can find this file at:
`$HOME/.netbeans/8.2/config/Services/MIMEResolver/user-defined-mime-resolver.xml`

On Windows, you can find the file at:
`%AppData%\Netbeans\8.2\config\Services\MIMEResolver\user-defined-mime-resolver.xml`

Basically, the first `<file>` block scans the filename of any PHP files to see if it contains the ".blade" substring. If so, the file is treated as a Twig file. If not, the second `<file>` block will treat the file as a normal PHP file.

You might need the "Twig Templates" NetBeans plugin in order to get proper highlighting:
`Tools > Plugins > Available Plugins > Twig Templates`

It's not perfect... Blade directives such as `@include` are still highlighted as plain text. However, I feel it is a marked improvement over PHP syntax highlighting.

The following sources were extremely helpful:

- [HOW TO: Declarative MIME Type Resolvers](http://bits.netbeans.org/7.4/javadoc/org-openide-filesystems/org/openide/filesystems/doc-files/HOWTO-MIME.html)
- [DTD Grammar Documentation](http://bits.netbeans.org/7.4/javadoc/org-openide-filesystems/org/openide/filesystems/doc-files/resolverDocumentation.html)
- [David Benedeki's earlier answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29590298/5338557)

Comment: Relief from big headache. Thank you .

Comment: Worked in 11.2, for my phpunit.xml.dist file. (MIME type: text/xml)

Comment: if you can't find file, do "locate -b user-defined-mime-resolver.xm"

Answer (score 3):

A lot of people are developing on other systems, as I am on Centos 7, so this workaround almost worked.

For CentOS, and probably other systems as well, follow these steps, almost the same as above for Windows:

- Open Netbeans. Go to `Tools->Options->Miscellaneous` and select tab `Files`.
- In `File Extension` row, click `New` button. Enter `crazywrongname` as extension name (this is important for option 2)
- Below that, under `Associated File Type (MIME):` choose the option `TWIG (text/x-twig)`
- click `Apply` and then `OK`.
- Close Netbeans

**Option 1:**

The following steps are for **CentOS 7** and **NetBeans 8.1**, most probably for other systems as well, but if you can't find the file at that path, option 2 is below.

- open Terminal and open the file `/root/.netbeans/8.1/config/Services/MIMEResolver/user-defined-mime-resolver.xml` in your favourite text editor, e.g. run command `nano /root/.netbeans/8.1/config/Services/MIMEResolver/user-defined-mime-resolver.xml`
- find the parameter name "crazywrongname" in this file and change it to "blade.php"
- save the file
- open Netbeans and enjoy.

People from the future, you might try changing the Netbeans version in file path from option 1 to yours, like 14.3 or whatever is out in 2028.

**Option 2:**

If you can't find this file in the exact path as above, run this command to find it:

```
cd / && grep -rI --exclude-dir=proc --exclude-dir=sys crazywrongname *
```

This will start a search for the specific pattern on your whole system, starting at root. That's why we named the parameter `crazywrongname` - so it isn't found in any other file on the system, like `blade` would be. It will also exclude the folders that are not supposed to be accessed. If you don't exclude them, you will get errors and possibly hang your system. Also, some pink unicorns might die.

After you find the exact file path for your system, follow the remaining steps in option 1 for changing the parameter name.

Thank you, mysterious David Benedeki who disappeared from StackOverflow after answer which helped enormously :)

Comment: **Filepath for Centos7.3.1611/NetBeans8.2:**   `$HOME/.netbeans/8.2/config/Services/MIMEResolver/user-defined-mime-resolver.xml`  ...  Love CentOS

Answer (score 0):

For module development with custom *BladeDataObject file

```
@MIMEResolver.Registration(
        resource = "BladeResolver.xml",
        displayName = "#LBL_Blade_LOADER" 
)
```

and in the same package create the BladeResolver.xml file with the content

```
<MIME-resolver>
    <file>
        <ext name="php"/>
        <name name="blade" substring="true">
            <resolver mime="text/x-blade"/>
        </name>
    </file>
</MIME-resolver>
```