# How to add .blade.php extension in netbeans ide?

Tags: laravel-4, netbeans-8, php-5.5

Some previous posts have solutions that did not work.
I do not want to text editors like sublime. Are there any
plugins?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14903225/how-to-add-a-custom-file-extension-that-has-a-dot-blade-php-in-netbeans

Answer (score 1):

I created a bug report about this.  I will update this post when it is fixed.

Current Answer : You can't

https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=255675