# Define file type for .env files

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-8

As far as I know NetBeans IDE does not support or have a plugin that supports `.env` files (typically used to implement [Store config in the environment](https://12factor.net/config)) but I've found that [Ini files support](https://blogs.oracle.com/netbeansphp/ini-files-support-available) is good enough for my use case (I get syntax highlighting and *Toggle Comment* command. However, I'm unable to set the file type for a file that starts with a dot. I works fine for `foo.env` but not `.env` (it's handled as plain text).

I found a related question ([how to set file type for `foo.blade.php`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14903225/how-to-add-a-custom-file-extension-that-has-a-dot-blade-php-in-netbeans/36093157)) and I'm able to bypass the GUI restriction (you cannot enter a file extension with a dot) with a custom `user-defined-mime-resolver.xml` file. I've tried two variations:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE MIME-resolver PUBLIC "-//NetBeans//DTD MIME Resolver 1.1//EN" "http://www.netbeans.org/dtds/mime-resolver-1_1.dtd">
<MIME-resolver>
    <file>
        <ext name=".env"/>
        <ext name="env"/>
        <resolver mime="text/x-ini"/>
    </file>
</MIME-resolver>
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE MIME-resolver PUBLIC "-//NetBeans//DTD MIME Resolver 1.1//EN" "http://www.netbeans.org/dtds/mime-resolver-1_1.dtd">
<MIME-resolver>
    <file>
        <ext name="env"/>
        <name name=".env" substring="true"/>
        <resolver mime="text/x-ini"/>
    </file>
</MIME-resolver>
```

Can you figure out a trick or workaround or spot something I've missed? (Im using build *NetBeans IDE Dev Build 201804200002* if that matters.)

Comment: Did you figure out how to get syntax coloring of .env or example.conf files in Netbeans?

Comment: @Ryan No new findings, sorry. But Apache settings are an entirely different thing.